# How do I create a question function without referencing the variable 'score' multiple times?

Tags: python, syntax-error, variable-assignment

I have been trying to build a game In python. I have a question function that will run a question from the variables:

- correctanswer
- answer1
- answer2
- answer3
- answer4
- question
- and `answer` as an input
  Here is the code for the function:

```
    def question():
        print('question')
        print('A = ', answer1)
        print('B = ', answer2)
        print('C = ', answer3)
        print('D = ', answer4)
        answer = input('Remember, Case sensitive!\n')
    
        if answer == 'A':
            if correctanswer == 'A':
                print('Correct! Score +1')
                score = score + 1
                print('Score = ', score)
            else:
                print('Incorrect! The glowing device in my arm buzzed. The world around me started to pixelate. I felt a sharp zap in my arm and everything went black')
                print('Score - 1')
                score = score - 1
                print('Score = ', score)
                death.start()
                print('░▒█▀▀█░█▀▀▄░█▀▄▀█░█▀▀░░░▄▀▀▄░▄░░░▄░█▀▀░█▀▀▄')
                time.sleep(0.5)
                print('░▒█░▄▄░█▄▄█░█░▀░█░█▀▀░░░█░░█░░█▄█░░█▀▀░█▄▄▀')
                time.sleep(0.5)
                print('░▒█▄▄▀░▀░░▀░▀░░▒▀░▀▀▀░░░░▀▀░░░░▀░░░▀▀▀░▀░▀▀')
                question()
        elif answer == 'B':
            if correctanswer == 'B':
                print('Correct! Score +1')
                score = score + 1
                print('Score = ', score)
            else:
                print('Incorrect! The glowing device in my arm buzzed. The world around me started to pixelate. I felt a sharp zap in my arm and everything went black')
                print('Score - 1')
                score = score - 1
                print('Score = ', score)
                death.start()
                print('░▒█▀▀█░█▀▀▄░█▀▄▀█░█▀▀░░░▄▀▀▄░▄░░░▄░█▀▀░█▀▀▄')
                time.sleep(0.5)
                print('░▒█░▄▄░█▄▄█░█░▀░█░█▀▀░░░█░░█░░█▄█░░█▀▀░█▄▄▀')
                time.sleep(0.5)
                print('░▒█▄▄▀░▀░░▀░▀░░▒▀░▀▀▀░░░░▀▀░░░░▀░░░▀▀▀░▀░▀▀')
                question()
        elif answer == 'C':
            if correctanswer == 'C':
                print('Correct! Score +1')
                score = score + 1
                print('Score = ', score)
            else:
                print('Incorrect! The glowing device in my arm buzzed. The world around me started to pixelate. I felt a sharp zap in my arm and everything went black')
                print('Score - 1')
                score = score - 1
                print('Score = ', score)
                death.start()
                print('░▒█▀▀█░█▀▀▄░█▀▄▀█░█▀▀░░░▄▀▀▄░▄░░░▄░█▀▀░█▀▀▄')
                time.sleep(0.5)
                print('░▒█░▄▄░█▄▄█░█░▀░█░█▀▀░░░█░░█░░█▄█░░█▀▀░█▄▄▀')
                time.sleep(0.5)
                print('░▒█▄▄▀░▀░░▀░▀░░▒▀░▀▀▀░░░░▀▀░░░░▀░░░▀▀▀░▀░▀▀')
                question()
        if answer == 'D':
            if correctanswer == 'D':
                print('Correct! Score +1')
                score = score + 1
                print('Score = ', score)
            else:
                print('Incorrect! The glowing device in my arm buzzed. The world around me started to pixelate. I felt a sharp zap in my arm and everything went black')
                print('Score - 1')
                score = score - 1
                print('Score = ', score)
                death.start()
                print('░▒█▀▀█░█▀▀▄░█▀▄▀█░█▀▀░░░▄▀▀▄░▄░░░▄░█▀▀░█▀▀▄')
                time.sleep(0.5)
                print('░▒█░▄▄░█▄▄█░█░▀░█░█▀▀░░░█░░█░░█▄█░░█▀▀░█▄▄▀')
                time.sleep(0.5)
                print('░▒█▄▄▀░▀░░▀░▀░░▒▀░▀▀▀░░░░▀▀░░░░▀░░░▀▀▀░▀░▀▀')
                time.sleep(1)
                question()
        else:
            print('Invalid, try again')
            question()
```

As you can see there is no penalty for death except minus one point.
I get the syntax error:
`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'score' referenced before assignment`
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

code:

```
import time
def question(answer,correctanswer,score):
    print('question')
    print('A = ', answer[0])
    print('B = ', answer[1])
    print('C = ', answer[2])
    print('D = ', answer[3])
    answer = input('Remember, Case sensitive!\n')

    if not answer in ["A","B","C","D"]:
        print('Invalid, try again')
        question(answer,correctanswer,score)

    if answer == correctanswer:
        print('Correct! Score +1')
        score = score + 1
        print('Score = ', score)
    else:
        print('Incorrect! The glowing device in my arm buzzed. The world around me started to pixelate. I felt a sharp zap in my arm and everything went black')
        print('Score - 1')
        score = score - 1
        print('Score = ', score)
        print('░▒█▀▀█░█▀▀▄░█▀▄▀█░█▀▀░░░▄▀▀▄░▄░░░▄░█▀▀░█▀▀▄')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print('░▒█░▄▄░█▄▄█░█░▀░█░█▀▀░░░█░░█░░█▄█░░█▀▀░█▄▄▀')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print('░▒█▄▄▀░▀░░▀░▀░░▒▀░▀▀▀░░░░▀▀░░░░▀░░░▀▀▀░▀░▀▀')
        # question(nextanswer,nextcorrectanswer,score)

score = 0
question(["answer1","answer2","answer3","answer4"],"C",score)
```

result:

```
question
A =  answer1
B =  answer2
C =  answer3
D =  answer4
Remember, Case sensitive!
A
Incorrect! The glowing device in my arm buzzed. The world around me started to pixelate. I felt a sharp zap in my arm and everything went black
Score - 1
Score =  -1
░▒█▀▀█░█▀▀▄░█▀▄▀█░█▀▀░░░▄▀▀▄░▄░░░▄░█▀▀░█▀▀▄
░▒█░▄▄░█▄▄█░█░▀░█░█▀▀░░░█░░█░░█▄█░░█▀▀░█▄▄▀
░▒█▄▄▀░▀░░▀░▀░░▒▀░▀▀▀░░░░▀▀░░░░▀░░░▀▀▀░▀░▀▀

question
A =  answer1
B =  answer2
C =  answer3
D =  answer4
Remember, Case sensitive!
C
Correct! Score +1
Score =  1
```

Answer (score 0):

If the score is only referenced in the question function, try assigning it the value of 0 at the start of the function.

If you need to reference it outside of the function, try assigning it a value outside of the function and passing it in.

Comment: What do you mean by 'passing it in'?

Answer (score 0):

### A function that adds scores

You can use another function called `addscore()` outside the `question()` function which adds points to the score and print out everything necessary.

```
def addscore(score, add=0, subtract=0):
    if add > 0:
        print(f'Correct! Score + {add}')
    elif subtract > 0:
        print('Incorrect! The glowing device in my arm buzzed. The world around me started to pixelate. I felt a sharp zap in my arm and everything went black')
        print(f'Score - {subtract}')
        
    score = score + add - subtract
    print('Score = ', score)
    
    if subtract > 0:
        death.start()
        print('░▒█▀▀█░█▀▀▄░█▀▄▀█░█▀▀░░░▄▀▀▄░▄░░░▄░█▀▀░█▀▀▄')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print('░▒█░▄▄░█▄▄█░█░▀░█░█▀▀░░░█░░█░░█▄█░░█▀▀░█▄▄▀')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print('░▒█▄▄▀░▀░░▀░▀░░▒▀░▀▀▀░░░░▀▀░░░░▀░░░▀▀▀░▀░▀▀')
        question()

    return score
```

### Implementation

After that, you can implement this function into the original `question()` function. With this, you can add more than one point.

**For example**
This adds 5 points and prints the message.

```
score = addscore(score, add=5)
```

Or this subtracts 3 points.

```
score = addscore(score, subtract=3)
```

Have fun!